# struts2 interceptor

Tags: struts2, interceptorstack

In my struts2 xml file, I see this interceptor def:

```
<interceptors>
<interceptor-stack name="dividendinterceptorstack">
<interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
<interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
</interceptor-stack>
```

But where is the actual class defined for dividendinterceptorstack? it is not in the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dividendinterceptorstack is a stack (collection) of interceptors.

If you can't find this stack definition - What does your package enclosing the above snippet extend from? Look in the package's 
hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Interceptor stacks are not classes, they are collections of interceptors run in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="alias" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="autowiring" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.interceptor.ActionAutowiringInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="chain" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="conversionError" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.StrutsConversionErrorInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="cookie" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CookieInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="clearSession" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ClearSessionInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="createSession" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CreateSessionInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="exception" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="fileUpload" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="i18n" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="logger" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="modelDriven" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="scopedModelDriven" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="params" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="actionMappingParams" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ActionMappingParametersInteceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="prepare" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="staticParams" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="scope" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ScopeInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="servletConfig" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="sessionAutowiring" class="org.apache.struts2.spring.interceptor.SessionContextAutowiringInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="timer" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="token" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="tokenSession" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="validation" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="workflow" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="store" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MessageStoreInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="checkbox" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="profiling" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="roles" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.RolesInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="jsonValidation" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.JSONValidationInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="annotationWorkflow" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.annotations.AnnotationWorkflowInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="multiselect" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor" />

            <!-- Basic stack -->
            <interceptor-stack name="basicStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="params">
                    <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

i just picked this up from struts-dafault.xml file located in struts core jar so you can see interceptor ref name has already been defined so we are just refereeing them when we are declaring our own stack